# Select node based on child node value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I would like to select only those node where child node value matches a certain value.

Here is my orig XML:

This is my orig XML

```
<Entry>
 <Name>AAA</Name>
 <line id="1">A</line>
 <line id="2">B</line>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <Name>BBB</Name>
 <line id="1">C</line>
 <line id="2">D</line>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <Name>AAA</Name>
 <line id="1">E</line>
 <line id="2">F</line>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <Name>CCC</Name>
 <line id="1">G</line>
 <line id="2">H</line>
</Entry>
```

I would like to extract all entries where Name = 'AAA', so the result would be:

```
<Entry>
 <Name>AAA</Name>
 <line id="1">A</line>
 <line id="2">B</line>
</Entry>
<Entry>
 <Name>AAA</Name>
 <line id="1">E</line>
 <line id="2">F</line>
</Entry>
```

I am limited to using XSLT 1.0.

Please provide any guidance. I am stuck on how to drop all sub-nodes for others that do not match.

regards,
Rahul

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following will select all entry nodes with subnodes 'Name' that equal AAA.

```
//Entry[Name = "AAA"]
```

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this (List element added to get well-formed xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <List>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//Entry[Name='AAA']"/>
    </List>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Entry">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
//Name[text()='AAA']/..
```

find all `Name` nodes whose text content is AAA, then move up one level to Name's parent node, which'd be `Entry`.